# Why does an iOS app delay sending google analytics tracking calls ? How to control?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-analytics

Here is the scenario:

- Environment: In both iOS simulator and iPhone production app
- 1:00 PM - connect Charles to iOS
- 1:00 PM - open app
- 1:00 PM to 1:15 PM - perform user actions
- 1:00 PM to 1:15 PM - no google analytics events recorded in GA
- After 1:15 PM - Google Analytics events start recording in batches. But no events related before 1:15 PM

**- Google Analytics missing data from 1:00 PM to 1:15 PM.**

After some time

- 3:00 PM - start a new session in app
- 3:00 PM - google analytics events recorded correctly this time in charles/proxyman

This is not a one-time scenario. Overall: Because of missing sessions (like 1:00 PM to 1:15 PM), 40-50% of our transactions are missing in iOS

**Why is iOS not able to send events during the first start of the app in that day ?**

**How to control it ?**